# Partitioning connected faces of polyhedra (the floor of a game level)

Tags: graphics, 3d, geometry, computational-geometry, partitioning

I have a set of polyhedra that make up a game level, and I'd like to partition the floor.  Basically, I need a generic way to divide up areas where players can be into labelled zones.  Are there any algorithms or an established set of procedures for doing this?

Assuming there isn't anything standard, I'd appreciate some guidance on how to go about this since I'm not very familiar with the domain.  I've seen some partitioning algorithms for polygons in CGAL which I like, so my intuition is to generate polygons from the floor and then use those algorithms.

Here's my plan:

1. Find all upward-facing faces of floor polyhedra: Start at an initial point on a known floor polyhedron where players can be and traverse connected polyhedra that intersect at a smooth enough angle (i.e. are not walls).  Pick a point in the sky and iterate through all the faces of floor polyhedra for which that point is on the positive side (I have orientation data for the faces).
2. Find planes to separate overlapping floor areas along the z-axis.  I have some ideas of how to go about this, but I suspect there's an algorithm that will do it.
3. Use the first two coordinates of now-divided floors to make polygons and run the partition algorithm on each of them.

Example:

Suppose I have 3D shape data of an office building with two floors and a staircase connecting the floors.  Everything is in 3D so a floor is represented by a polyhedron with thickness as are the walls and staircase.  I want to partition the upward face of each floor in order to plan out cubicle locations.  I really don't care about the cubicles on one floor in relation to cubicles on the other floor.  Rather than having one 3D space that's partitioned, it makes sense to me to break this up into two 2D spaces to partition individually.

Note: This example isn't perfect because in the example I don't care about partitioning the staircase, but in my game world I do.  So I can't just remove the staircase and have my two separated floors, but I could, for instance, slice it and separate the floors with a plane.

Comment: It is very unclear what you want. Can you show an example? Could it be that you are confusing polyhedra with polygons?

Comment: My goal is to break up a 3D level into discrete zones.  The level is made up of polyhedra, but I only care about the player's position in 2D terms, except where the level overlaps (e.g. different floors in a building) in which case I care about the z coordinate only as a way to differentiate between the overlaps.  I added an example which will hopefully make things clearer.

Comment: So what is the result you would like for the two-level building? Two partitions (one for each level)? Am I correct that the partitions must not overlap if projected in the xy-plane?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly like what I'm trying to do.

Comment: This sounds like multi-cut. Find the overlapping parts and define a terminal pair for each pair of parts. Then define the cost of cutting apart two adjacent polyhedra/polygons (edge weights) from the geometry (e.g. dihedral angle). Run this definition through a multi-cut solver and you'll have your result. Is that something that would work for your scenario?

Comment: That sounds like it could be what I'm after, but I'm not entirely sure.  I'll need to do some reading on multi-cut, which I can't do right at this moment.